# Proving using algebraic form of rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, rotations

I am lost as to how to prove, using algebraic form of rotations, that $R_a$ $\circ$ $R_b$ = $R_{a+b}$. To solve this, one needs to create separate matrix such that $R_a$ and $R_b$ are 2x2 matrices with arbitrary values and then add those 2 matrices to get $R_{a+b}$ to find the composition right? I have been trying to mentally come up with a strategy to prove this but have yet to come to anything that seems correct. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is that $R_a \circ R_b \neq R_a + R_b$, so you do not *add* the matrices in order to compose their corresponding functions, but you *multiply* them using matrix multiplication. Furthermore you can use that every rotation matrix is given by

$$R_a = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(a) & -\sin(a) \\ \sin(a) & \cos(a) \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. After sleeping on the question, I got to the same conclusion and realized I was just overthinking it. Thanks!